# Can a map use java.text.Collator?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, collation

Im using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a data cache retrieved from the database and currently the way to get a string is via `map.get()`. However, some parts of the code directly queries from the database instead of just using the cache since some joins are needed for those cases. The problem now, the `collation` on the table is causing different behavior between text comparison via SQL comparison (uses the table collation) and text comparison via Java using `map.get()`.

I have read about `java.text.Collator` but it needs the use of `collator.Compare` to be able to use it properly. Is there a way to force a map in using a fixed `Collator`.

By the way the collation in this situation is using Japanese character where half-width and full-width Japanese are the same when compared in SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a TreeMap with a Collator properly configured for your case. Here is an example where uppercase and lowercase latin characters are considered equivalent:

```
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);

Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>(collator);

map.put("ABC", "foo");

System.out.println(map.get("abc"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate `Collator` with `Japanese` `Locale` like:

```
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance( Locale.JAPANESE );
```

And then you can compare the strings like:

```
int comparison = collator.compare( strOne, strTwo );
```