# Sorting List with non Latin alphabet in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I need to sort a LinkedHashMap by key, which I have achieved by converting into a List and using `Collections.sort`. But it only works with the English alphabet and now I need to do the same with Russian and it doesn't work anymore.

Please see my code below. I have tried adding `Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("ru", "RU"));` but it didn't help...

```
    private static void sortKeys(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> wordSet = map.entrySet();

        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> wordEntryList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(wordSet);

        Collections.sort(wordEntryList, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("ru", "RU"));
                return collator.compare(o1.getKey(), o2.getKey());
            }
        });

        map.clear();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> m : wordEntryList) {
            map.put(m.getKey(), m.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Key is a Russian word, value is a number and it needs to be sorted by key. Please see the example below.

Expected:

1. наше - 18
2. пушкин - 18
3. полете - 15
4. тигруля - 15
5. игрив - 12
6. котенок - 12
7. красив - 11
8. манул - 11

Actual:

1. пушкин - 18
2. наше - 18
3. тигруля - 15
4. полете - 15
5. котенок - 12
6. игрив - 12
7. манул - 11
8. красив - 11

The words are keys in the Map, the numbers -values. The numbers are sorted separately and have no play in the sorting.

Comment: There is a solution to a really similar problem, but it is in PHP. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187285/sorting-russian-english-list

 You may want to take a look

Comment: What is your input and expected output? English speaker here.

Comment: Give brief example input data, and show expected results versus actual results.

Comment: Well, OP wants to sort as per Russian alphabet.

Comment: Post your example inputs and outputs as text here, not images. Provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `map` argument must be LinkedHashMap as shown in the first answer. Or try [using a TreeMap with a collator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6895599/2834978) .

Comment: You still have not shown a consistent MCVE. When I run your code with this input {пушкин=18, тигруля=15, манул=11, котенок=12, красив=11, наше=18, игрив=12, полете=15} I get this result: {игрив=12, котенок=12, красив=11, манул=11, наше=18, полете=15, пушкин=18, тигруля=15} which does not match your "Actual" result. In none of my experiments could I match either your expected or actual results. For example, I always end up with `наше` in the middle, never in the first or second position. While I know nothing about Russian language or Cyrillic alphabet, something else is going on with your code.

Comment: @BasilBourque apparently, the map is supposed to be sorted descending by value and ascending by key only as a secondary criteria. But it doesn’t help that this has not been specified in the question nor reflected in the shown code nor the accepted answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque you are right, here mistake in Expected result of author

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code works fine

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("ггг", 4);
map.put("ввв", 3);
map.put("ааа", 1);
map.put("ббб", 2);
sortKeys(map);
System.out.println(map);
```

prints

```
{ааа=1, ббб=2, ввв=3, ггг=4}
```

Possible issue - you trying to use HashMap instead of LinkedHashMap.
HashMap unable to keep order, but LinkedHashMap can do that.

One more thing. Collections.sort() accepts List of Comparable. 
You trying to use Map.Entry<String, Integer> as element of list. 
Entry does not extends Comparable, thats why you cannot just simply write

```
Collections.sort(wordEntryList); // compile error
```

And final addition. If you want to get rid of Collator, you can write something like that

```
private static void sortLinkedMap(LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map) {
    ArrayList<String> keysList = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    Collections.sort(keysList); // works fine with keys(String) as elements
    HashMap<String, Integer> tempMap = new HashMap<>(map);
    map.clear();
    for (String key : keysList) {
        map.put(key, tempMap.get(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the sample data in the Question? I did, and I cannot match either the actual or expected results shown in the Question.

Comment: sorry, there were absent sample data when I answer. Actually sorting works perfectly. Currently here mistake in Expected result of author, it should be sorted like you wrote in the comment above https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use a `NavigableMap`/`SortedMap` rather than write all that code.

```java
new TreeMap <>(                   // `TreeMap` implements `NavigableMap`, keeping keys in sorted order.
    Collator.getInstance(         // `Collator` implements `Comparator`, needed to define the way in which to compare our keys of Russian text.
        new Locale.Builder()
        .setLanguage( "ru" )
        .setScript( "Cyrl" )
        .build() 
    ) 
)                                 // Returns an empty `TreeMap`. 
.putAll(                          // Copies the mappings from other map to this map.
        Map.of(                   // Convenient literals syntax to produce an unmodifiable `Map`. 
                "игрив" , 12 ,
                "котенок" , 12 ,
                "пушкин" , 18 ,
                "тигруля" , 15 ,
                "красив" , 11 ,
                "наше" , 18 ,
                "манул" , 11 ,
                "полете" , 15
        )                          // Returns an unmodifiable `Map`. 
)
```

And call `toString` to produce a textual representation of the `NavigableMap`.

> {игрив=12, котенок=12, красив=11, манул=11, наше=18, полете=15, пушкин=18, тигруля=15}

## Details

Caveat: I know nothing about the Russian language nor the Cyrillic script.

### `NavigableMap`

You are working too hard. If you want a map where the keys are kept sorted, use an implementation of [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) (or its predecessor [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html)).

The [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) class is one such implementation.

```
NavigableMap< String , Integer > map = new TreeMap<>( myLinkedHashMap ) ;
```

Since you want to sort strings, you should tell the `TreeMap` to use a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html), a specific [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Collator.html). In your case, you want the [Russian language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_language) using the [Cyrillic script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script).

```java
Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage( "ru" ).setScript( "Cyrl" ).build();
Comparator comparator = Collator.getInstance( locale );  // `Collator` class implements `Comparator` interface.
NavigableSet < String > sorted = new TreeSet <>( comparator );
```

Add the contents of your existing `LinkedHashMap` to this `NavigableMap`. Call [`Map#putAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) to copy over the mappings.

```
sorted.putAll( myLinkedHashMap ) ;
```

As the entries are added to this new navigable map, the keys are maintained in a sorted order using that `Comparator`/`Collator` to compare the strings of Russian text.

Let's try this with a map created using [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V)) for convenient literals syntax.

Here is complete example code.

```java
Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage( "ru" ).setScript( "Cyrl" ).build();
Comparator comparator = Collator.getInstance( locale );  // `Collator` class implements `Comparator` interface.
NavigableMap < String, Integer > map = new TreeMap <>( comparator );

map.putAll(
        Map.of(
                "игрив" , 12 ,
                "котенок" , 12 ,
                "пушкин" , 18 ,
                "тигруля" , 15 ,
                "красив" , 11 ,
                "наше" , 18 ,
                "манул" , 11 ,
                "полете" , 15
        )
);

System.out.println( "map = " + map );
```

When run in Java 16 on macOS, I get the following. See the same code and same results in Java 12 [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/cZZMIt).

> map = {игрив=12, котенок=12, красив=11, манул=11, наше=18, полете=15, пушкин=18, тигруля=15}

---

I have been unable to get either your expected or actual results, after several experiments. While I do not know Russian or Cyrillic, I must ask:

- Are you sure that your expected results are correct?
- How *exactly* did you get your actual results?

The [comment by Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843530/sorting-list-with-non-latin-alphabet-in-java/67845871#comment119998468_67843530) speculates that you want to sort on two levels, first by the value, and then by the key. If so, you *really* should have stated this in the Question. I'll not address the issue here. But for reference, see [*Using comparator with multiple comparators*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51706742/642706).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to simplify the sorting by using the Java API and return the new map:

```
var sorted = new TreeMap(Collator.getInstance(new Locale("ru", "RU")));
sorted.putAll(map);
return sorted;
```

This works by delegating to the TreeMap that sorts by key.
The sort method is determined by the Comparator (which Collator is).